# Formatting Monthly dates in Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, datetime, indexing

I want to modify the `Monthly_idxs` so that it outputs the monthly data ranges starting from the beginning minute of the month `-01 00:00:00+00:00` instead of the current output. I want to also include the month of the initial index of which is October but the output starts the initial `Monthly_idxs` from November. How would I be able to get the Expected Output below?

```
import pandas as pd 

# Creates 1 minute data range between date_range(a, b)
l = (pd.DataFrame(columns=['NULL'],
                  index=pd.date_range('2015-10-08T13:40:00Z', '2016-01-04T21:00:00Z',
                                      freq='1T'))
       .index.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
       .tolist()
)

#Month Indexes
Monthly_idxs = pd.date_range(l[0], l[-1], freq='MS')
```

Output:

```
['2015-11-01 13:40:00+00:00', '2015-12-01 13:40:00+00:00',
               '2016-01-01 13:40:00+00:00']
```

Expected Output:

```
['2015-10-01 00:00:00+00:00', '2015-11-01 00:00:00+00:00','2015-12-01 00:00:00+00:00'
               '2016-01-01 00:00:00+00:00']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write `Monthly_idxs` using [`round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) and [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) to get the expected result :

```py
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

Monthly_idxs = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(min(l)).round('1d') - DateOffset(months=1), pd.Timestamp(max(l)).round('1d'), freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z").tolist()
```

Output :

```
['2015-10-01 00:00:00+0000',
 '2015-11-01 00:00:00+0000',
 '2015-12-01 00:00:00+0000',
 '2016-01-01 00:00:00+0000']
```

Thanks to @MrFuppes for the `DateOffset` idea.

Comment: I think you can use a [DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html), no need for the extra import

Comment: Thank you @MrFuppes, indeed that way we stay in pandas, clever ! I updated the answer :) !

Answer (score 0):

Your list conversion occurs too soon. You can use `resample` on your dataframe and then use `format` to get the string list of your resampled index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['NULL'],
                  index=pd.date_range('2015-10-08T13:40:00Z', '2016-01-04T21:00:00Z',
                                      freq='1T'))

Month_begin = df.resample('MS').asfreq()
Monthly_idxs = Month_begin.index.format()
print(Monthly_idxs)
```

Output:

```
['2015-10-01 00:00:00+00:00', '2015-11-01 00:00:00+00:00', '2015-12-01 00:00:00+00:00', '2016-01-01 00:00:00+00:00']
```